# Need Help in Downloading Applications from Android Market?

Tags: google-play-store

I had an android mobile whose version is 1.5 , in that device, can i see the application in the market whose versions are 1.6 and above, is it possible to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Being able to see applications targeted at higher Android version is useless, because it won't install or run anyway.

Comment: Can you ensure me, this is any filters in android market, for filtering the Applications

Comment: @Tilsan I am 100% sure you cannot see applications targeted for 1.6 or higher from an unmodded version of 1.5

Comment: xi: Unmodded version means, in the sense how you said it is unmodded, pls tell clearly

Comment: Unmodded means not modified, ie. not rooted.

Answer (score 5):

Only one way to find out. Try it.

Answer (score 3):

It won't matter.  You can only run apps where the developer has either set the target to Android 1.5 or the mintarget to 1.5 (with a target to 1.6+, meaning they'd have to be careful that Android 1.5 doesn't make API calls that do not exist yet for 1.5).